# Logistic regression for non-categorical data prediction

Tags: python, regression, logistic-regression

It is well know that logistic regression widely being used for classification problems where categorical variables are used. I am started exploring whether it is possible to apply logistic regression for numerical variables or not!

For example, let say, I have dataframe (`df`) that includes four variables (>3000 datasets) coming from wind turbines as follows

```
     t                 wind speed  pressure   power_output  
2012-03-01 00:00:00        7.5      900.12       788.1564
2012-03-01 00:00:10        8.5      900.86       991.8323
2012-03-01 00:00:20        5.6      900.72       985.0856
2012-03-01 00:00:30        8.9      900.29       879.3877
2012-03-01 00:00:40        10.1     900.58       1118.800
```

Here my target variable is `power_output`. Based on other variables, I would like to predict the `power_output`. Is this possible via `logistic regression`?

It is worth to note that, the relationship between `power_output` and `wind speed` almost like S-shaped simiar to sigmoid function.

I have written codes but that its not taking `continious` label. And getting this error `ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'`

```
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv').dropna()
df.head()

X=pd.iloc[:,[0,2]].values
y=pd.iloc[:,3].values      # power_output

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc= StandardScaler()
X_train=sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test=sc.fit_transform(X_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier=LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred=classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: No, no, no. _Linear_ regression, or "continuous" regression.

Comment: The data is nonlinear hence cant use linear regression.

Comment: You can use non-linear terms in a "linear" regression in order to account for the non-linearity of a given data-generating process.

Answer (score 1):

I think logistic regression is not the correct approach here. The problem is that logistic regression determines the probability of a label. With `power_output` being a number you have an infinite amount of labels.

A better approach in my opinion is to use a `Regressor`, which approximates a function between continuous X and Y values.

I would try the [AdaBoostRegressor from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostRegressor.html), which statistically determines the best function to approximate. You do not have to change too much as it is from the same library (sklearn).

Alternatively, you can use [LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) and transform your data (e.g. with [PolynominalFeatures](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html)) in order to approximate some function that has a higher dimension than linear.

Comment: Yes. I know. but just looking is there is any way to solve this via logistic or not.  Can you please give some example of 'Regressor' ?

Comment: Yes I edited anwser. I would try AdaBoostRegressor as it is very simple and gives you good results.

Comment: I would look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The physical relation between density, wind speed and power output of wind turbines is known: `P = p * v^3 * C` with `p` the density (which correlated directly to pressure), `v` the wind speed (up to the [cut-out speed](https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Wind_power#Wind_Speed)), and `C` a wind turbine dependent constant factor.

So really, you only have to fit the factor C which can be done with [scipy's curve fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression is 99% of the time used to predict a **binary outcome**.
We can quote as most famous example the Titanic example: based on data of every passenger, you could try to determine whether they survived or not (i.e. lived or died (so binary outcome)).
To me, if you try to predict a value based on other parameters, you should try to use another algorithm, but **you can't use either a linear algorithm nor a logistic regression**.
Maybe you could try to use **random forest regressor** of the scikit-learn module, but i am not too sure how it would work.

Edit: when I say binary outcome, it can also count as classification between two classes